# Problems installing Wget for firefox un Ubuntu 14.04 (along with fireget extension)

Tags: 14.04, firefox, make, downloaders

I followed the the instructions in [HOWTO: install Gwget and Fireget Firefox extension](http://bit.ly/1RdQkv8)

but when I'm trying to compile Gwget (using instruction in the INSTALL file) I have the following error messages :

```
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~/Téléchargements/gwget-1.0.4$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gconftool-2... /usr/bin/gconftool-2
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0... ./configure: line 3598: intltool-update: command not found
 found
configure: error: Your intltool is too old.  You need intltool 0.35.0 or later.
```

Then when I type make :

```
laurent06000@PC-DE-LDP:~/Téléchargements/gwget-1.0.4$ make
make: *** Pas de cible spécifiée et aucun makefile n'a été trouvé. Arrêt.
```

Moreover when I try to open the FireGet-0.6.xpi file it tells me that this version is incompatible with my Firefox version (41).

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Install a current version of `intltool`. My Ubuntu 14.04.3 system has

```
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  intltool       0.50.2-2     all          Utility scripts for international
```

This:

```
sudo apt-get install intltool
```

should do it.

The other error message, which Google translate says is:

```
No target specified and no makefile found. Off.
```

is caused by the earlier failure of the `./configure` script, which was supposed to create a `[Mm]akefile`, but did not. Fix the first problem, and this one will go away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this one was not a good idea. After I issued the "sudo apt-get install intltool" command, I tried within FF it but it  cut all my uGet downloads I was doing and moreover forced me to a hard reboot.